# If $\inf\{b\in\mathbb{R}\mid\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-ax_n-by_n}<+\infty\}=1-a$ for all $a\in [0,1]$, does this equality hold for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, exponential-sum

Let $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n=1}^{+\infty},\left\{y_n\right\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}\subset [0,+\infty)$ be two sequences of non-negative real numbers. Suppose there exist $\lambda\ge 1, c\ge 0$ such that $\frac{1}{\lambda}x_n-c\leq y_n\leq \lambda x_n+c$, and $\inf\left\{a\in \mathbb{R}\mid \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-ax_n}<+\infty\right\}=\inf\left\{b\in \mathbb{R}\mid \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-by_n}<+\infty\right\}=1$.

Consider a series: $P(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-ax_n-by_n}$.

For each $a\in \mathbb{R}$, denote $\varphi(a)=\inf\left\{b\in\mathbb{R}\mid P(a,b)<+\infty\right\}$. It can be shown that $-\infty<\varphi(a)<+\infty$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

If $\varphi(a)=1-a$ for all $a\in [0,1]$, can we deduce $\varphi(a)=1-a$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Could you describe the origin of this problem ? What have you tried ? Perhaps you have studied some examples.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc This problem has a geometric and ergodic theoretical background. A notion called ''Manhattan Curve'' is defined so as to compare two metrics $d,d_{\ast}$ on a (finitely generated) group $G$. In some special cases, it is proven that these two metrics are "roughly similar" if and only if their corresponding Manhattan curve is a straight line. The Manhattan curve just look like the curve $\{(a,\varphi(a))\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ as defined in the question. I'm curious whether a part of this Manhattan curve is a straight line is directly equivalent to say the entire curve is straight?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc For more details of this background, check for [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.13451).

Comment: Or do we know any smoothness or analyticity of the function $\varphi$?